# T-SQL Parent Child hierarchy

Tags: t-sql

I have a table and initially it has one entry as follows

```
ID   ParentID  Title
1    NULL      All
```

This table I am using to create tree structures. The table needs to be filled with the following data stored in CSV file. Each line represents one tree path

```
All;World               
All;World;NA
All;World;NA;Canada             //Here each item represents the tree node and separated by ;

--
--
```

I am looking to write a query which will take input like All;World;NA and create entry in table if does not exist and return the ID of the created entry or an existing entry. So in my example with input All;World;NA the table should look like this after query is run

```
ID   ParentID  Title
1    NULL      All
2    1         World
3    2         NA
```

and it has created 2 entries and ID=3 returned since path All;World;NA represents ID=3

If I give another input like All;World;NA;Canada, then it will create one more entry and ID=4 returned.
If I re-run query with input All;World;NA;Canada then it will find that entry exists and return ID=4

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can start with:

```
CREATE TABLE TREE
(
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    ParentID INT,
    Name varchar(32)
);
GO

CREATE PROC InsertIntoTree @node varchar(512)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @xml xml,@str varchar(100),@delimiter varchar(10)
    SET @delimiter =';'
    SET @xml = cast(('<X>'+replace(@node,@delimiter ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') as xml)

    DECLARE @nodes TABLE (NodeName varchar(32));

    INSERT INTO @nodes(NodeName)
    SELECT C.value('.', 'varchar(10)') as NodeName FROM @xml.nodes('X') as X(C)

    DECLARE @nodename varchar(32)
    DECLARE @nodeid int
    DECLARE @parentNodeId int
    SET @parentNodeId = null

    SELECT TOP 1 @nodename=Nodename from @nodes 
    WHILE (@@ROWCOUNT <> 0 and @nodename IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @nodeid = null

        SELECT @nodeid=Id FROM TREE WHERE Name=@nodename

        IF(@nodeid is null )
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO TREE(ParentID,Name) VALUES(@parentNodeId,@nodename)
            SET @nodeid = @@IDENTITY
        END
        SET @parentNodeId = @nodeid

        delete from @nodes where NodeName=@nodename
        SELECT TOP 1 @nodename=Nodename from @nodes 
    END

END
GO
```

To test it:

```
InsertIntoTree 'A;B;C'
select * from tree
```

I leave it to the ready to optimize.